# Visual studio 2017 create invalid Nuget reference of System.ValueTuple (4.3.1) for new F# .Net core project?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, .net-core

I have Visual Studio V15.7.5. It always generates a reference to System.ValueTuple (4.3.1) after new F# .Net core projects are created.

[image: Solution Explorer]

And it also has a compiling warning of

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. WebApplication6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade `System.ValueTuple` to version 4.5.0 and the issue will be resolved.

**EDIT**
You can do this through the nuget manager by clicking on the Browse tab. Search for `System.ValueTuple`, make sure version 4.5.0 is selected (or maybe latest if this is viewed later), and click *Install*.

[Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/4412)

Comment: How to upgrade `System.ValueTuple`? There was only one update for `FSharp.Core` in NuGet update and I updated it from 4.3.x to 4.5.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I updated my answer with instructions. I assume you are using Nuget package manager. Paket would be the usual just adding a reference to it in the dependencies file.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Just so you are aware at the moment I believe F# 4.5 is still in preview, although it is apparently very stable I am not sure on how well it plays with other packages. Not saying it doesn't... just letting you know.